# bash file parameter problem

Tags: unix, bash, file-transfer

i write bash file to copy files from unix to windows and i pass the path of files as parameter to bash file :-
`scp -r /$1/ user@hostname:/cygdrive/c/unix_file`

when i execute the bash and don't pass any parameter it is copy all file in "current directory "

example :-

roor@hostname/>./bash.sh
now it copy all file in root .... when i test exit code it is equal ( 0 ) !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass an argument then its parameter value is considered to be an empty string. Test the parameter for a zero-length string (with `if` and `[` or `[[`) and fail if it is one. And don't forget to quote the parameter in the command (`scp ... /"$1"/ ...`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify a default directory that will be in effect if you don't supply a parameter:

```
scp -r "/${1:-default/directory}/" user@hostname:/cygdrive/c/unix_file
```

in which you would replace "default/directory" with whatever you'd like.